# Android: Possible to add a fragment to a Viewflipper?

Tags: android, viewflipper, fragment

Working on some code, I found myself in a bit of a pickle.

I have fragments to display the various pages of my app.  I had a search fragment and an options fragment which I want to interact with one another.  Is it possible to have a fragment which can be accessed normally and have it accessed using a viewflipper?

The Options Fragment has a viewflipper in it which allows me to display the various menus that are involved with it.  However, I need to be able to access the search function through the viewflipper on the Options Fragment, whilst also being able to access it as a normal Fragment (Not at the same time, but able to access it either via the fragment on the tab bar or from the viewflipper in the options Fragment).

So far I have used the following code to activate a viewflipper view change:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
                        if(moreViewFlipper.getChildAt(1) != null)//Check if any previously checked views
                        {
                            moreViewFlipper.removeViewAt(1);
                        }
                        switch(pos){
                        case 0: // Profile
                            moreViewFlipper.addView(createProfileView(ctx), 1);
                            moreViewFlipper.setInAnimation(SlideAnimation.inFromRightAnimation());
                            moreViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(SlideAnimation.outToLeftAnimation());
                            moreViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
                            break;
...
```

Is it possible to use the code above (adding the fragment's view as a child to the moreViewFlipper?  I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this.

---

EDIT:
A friend very kindly managed to point out how I could do this after some experimentation.  Apparently, it is possible to place a fragment within a view if you place it in the the xml file which holds the view which you wish to add the fragment to.

In this case, I created a new xml file and placed the fragment inside a Linearview with a back button.  I used  the code above to call a function which inflated the view and brought it into the viewflipper and voala!  it works as long as you have a different ID for your fragment as you do for the original one (if it is a case like mine, being called in 2 instances).

Again, sorry for wasting people's time, but thank you for your kindness.

Comment: yes, it is possible ... or no, it isn't ... it depends on createProfileView, moreViewFlipper, SlideAnimation.inFromRightAnimation, SlideAnimation.outToLeftAnimation ... by fragment you mean Fragment from android ? ... in other words ... it's not possible to answer that question without magic orb

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of the question, long day.  MoreViewFlipper is the viewflipper, inside the android Fragment optionsFragment.  creatprofileview merely creates a view in the option fragment, allows me to display user info.  I was merely curious if I could add an Android Fragment to a Viewflipper, which is itself within a Fragment, as a view?

Comment: if i understand you correctly you wana add Fragment into Fragment? that's not possible ...  i've faced the same problem, i had listview fragment on left and details fragmen on right in details fragment i've had tabs ... so i wana use fragments but after research i've found that it's not possible to have fragments in fragments ... i've ended with custom view...

Comment: (Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the information, I appreciate it.  Yes, I pretty much would like to add a Fragment to a Fragment, though I am somewhat saddened that it cant be done. i'll continue to investgate into it myself, but thanks for the forwarning not to spend too much tiem in it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. But may be someone else has a similar issue.

You can combine ViewFlipper and Fragments if you are using ViewPager. Put ViewPager -node inside your ViewFlipper -node in your main_layout.xml. The action bar will still stay on its place and you will be able to flip to the other view easily and backwards.

If you want to handle a hardware back button, put something like that in your main fragment activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        if(this.vf.getCurrentView() != this.findViewById(R.id.pager))     //vf is a ViewFlipper's instance
        {
            this.vf.showPrevious();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```